# Why does the south section of my border layout view start invisible?

Tags: java, swing

I mapped out some labels that are filled with data from a mysql via JDBC.  I have mapped out the data North, Center, and South on a border layout.

Here's a code snippet

```
panels = new JPanel();
    panels.setBackground(Color.blue);
    panels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panels, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    statuslabel = new JLabel(company.getDBstatus(1) + " ");
    statuslabel.setForeground(Color.white);
    statuslabel.setFont(new Font("ANDALUS", Font.BOLD, 16));
    statuslabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Status"));
    positionlabel = new JLabel(company.getDBposition(1) + " ");
    positionlabel.setForeground(Color.white);
    positionlabel.setFont(new Font("ANDALUS", Font.BOLD, 16));
    positionlabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Open Position"));
    referencelabel = new JLabel(company.getDBreference(1));
    referencelabel.setForeground(Color.white);
    referencelabel.setFont(new Font("ANDALUS", Font.BOLD, 16));
    referencelabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Reference"));
    panels.add(statuslabel);
    panels.add(positionlabel);
    panels.add(referencelabel);
    contentPane.add(panels, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Initially the SOUTH section is not visible. If I comment out resize supression, clicking a border will make South appear, also selecting something other then the initial record will make the  south appear as well.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you call `pack()` on the top level window? if so what is your order regarding calling `pack()` and `setResizable(false)`? In other words, which do you call first and which second? Have you tried swapping the order?

Comment: Added pack() and the problem went away.  Hope you solve your eel problem as easy!

Comment: I'd guess the problem is that the labels start with no content that is not " ".  OTOH I do not like guessing, which is one reason why I oft say.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Pack() solved this issue. It painted the south section of border layout along with the other active regions.